# Rails 4 export as csv: undefined method `attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am trying to export data to csv file. My code this

```
@products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { render text: @products.to_csv }
    end
```

and in my model

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << self.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

This is not working. I get this error

```
NoMethodError in ProductsController#index
undefined method `attributes' for #<Class:0x000000047e91c8>
```

I am in Rails 4 and ruby 2.2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)` instead of `self.attributes.values_at(*column_names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError in ProductsController#index undefined method
>   `attributes' for Class:0x000000047e91c8

As I said, you should use `product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)` instead of `self.attributes.values_at(*column_names)`

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
 end
```

[**Source**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

Comment: well it works but why it doesn't work with self.attributes.... It used to work when the project was in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

You are within a class method (`def self.to_csv`) of your model. Within this method `self` is the class `Product` not a product instance. But you want to access the attributes of a product instance. You iterate through `all` product objects. Therefore you need to access the current product object, which is given to you (`|product|`) for each iteration. So try `product.attributes`instead of `self.attributes`.